# I cannot install QGIS 2.4 on my Windows 7, 64 bit machine

Tags: qgis

I am running Windows 7, 64 bit and cannot install QGIS 2.4 after several days of trying. I have also tried downloading 2.2 with no avail. I keep getting this error:

[image: NSIS error]

The text of the error is:

> NSIS Error
>
> Installer integrity check has failed. Common causes include incomplete download and damaged media. Contact the installer's author to obtain a new copy.
>
> More information at: 
>   http://nsis.sf.net/NSIS_Error

Comment: install QGIS it in another folder (rather than program files) and run as administrator.

Comment: @Mapperz, could you expand on that a little bit. I am trying to do the basic install, download the .exe file, and when I try to run it (as a user and as admin), I get the above error message, so I don't even get a chance to tell where qgis to install.

Comment: Are you downloading it from this link? http://qgis.org/downloads/QGIS-OSGeo4W-2.4.0-1-Setup-x86_64.exe

Comment: Try the 32-bit version of QGIS. It runs fine on my 64-bit Windows 7.

Comment: I think I got it working! I was trying through the standalone installer. then I tried OSGeo4W as admin and just installed qgis (do I need grass, etc?). It gave me some errors during the install--couldn't find some files, but it apparently worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MattRota, In order to close out this question, please move your last comment to an "Answer" and in a day or two when StackExchange allows you, mark your answer as accepted (there is a delay for marking your own answer as accepted).  Thanks.

Comment: You should look into issues with your machine in general. I have had no problem installing QGIS 2.0 2.2 2.4, 64 bit and 32 bit versions, standalone and OSGeo4W versions. We do it on a large scale so talking 50 or 60 machines with no error messages.