# QGIS Download getting stuck, NSIS error?

Tags: qgis

I need to edit a DBF file, and I tried to install QGIS at http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html.

However, none of the standalone installers work. I tried installing 32/64bit, Latest/Long-term release, it didn't matter.  It would get stuck downloading the `.exe` file itself for about a half hour before it would seemingly finish. But then when I tried to run the file, get:

[image]

Then I found [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109618/i-cannot-install-qgis-2-4-on-my-windows-7-64-bit-machine) and I tried to install it using the OSGeo4W Network Installer, but even *that* got stuck at 6%. Is there anything I can do to solve this issue?? I tried this on two different computers and got the same result...

Comment: Your downloads are failing for some reason. They're big(ish) files (~290mb).  I just downloaded the 2.12 64bit installer with no problems, took about 10min. You may have a flaky internet connection, be behind a corporate proxy that's doing something funky, have an issue with your browser/download folder or something else entirely... Regardless, this isn't a GIS related question.